# LESS with Play 2.3.1 resulting in zero length main.css

Tags: playframework-2.0, less, sbt

I'm using the LESS compiler with Play 2.3.1.  I have installed the sbt-less plugin (v1.0.4) in my plugins.sbt file and enabled it in build.sbt with:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
```

The LESS compiler is invoked and builds the main.css in target\web\public\main\stylesheets directory.  The content of the file is correct.

In my index.scala.html file I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")' />
```

However when I point my browser at the application, the main.css is found but the size is zero.  The http status code is 304, not modified.

If I used activator to package my application for deployment, the main.css in the resulting .jar file is also zero.  I'm at a loss to understand where activator is getting the zero length main.css from and why it isn't getting the one generated by LESS.  Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Interestingly if we arbitrarily change `@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")` to something else like "test2.css", Play will generate an empty file called test2.css and return it.

So it seems there is no relation between the main.css that LESS is generating and the main.css returned by `@routes.Assets`.  That suggests that LESS is not putting the file where `@routes.Assets` expects it to be.

**SOLVED?**

We searched modules of the application and discovered a few zero size stylesheets/main.css files.  We deleted those and things started working.  I'm guessing they confused whatever magic was going on in the background.

**IN CONCLUSION**

This was a multimodule project.  I was working on the main but had already set up module directories, probably copied from somewhere.  Some of those modules had a zero size public/stylesheets/main.css files.  The "real" main.css generated by LESS was copied to the output first then overwritten by one of these empty main.css files.  Once they were all removed, we got the expected result.

Comment: What happens when you curl it?  That is, run curl http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.css.  A 304 status code will always return zero length content.  You may need to clear your browsers cache.

Comment: Comes up same.  Zero length, 304 status code.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a filter in place that's doing something weird?  A 304 status code will only be returned by the Play assets controller if you include an If-None-Match header, if you use curl, then there will be no If-None-Match header, so you can't get a 304 status code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I don't get status 304 with curl.  I was thinking of the browser navigating directly to main.css.  With curl, I get status code 200, Content-Length: 0.

Comment: Do you have an empty `main.css` in `public/stylesheets`?

Comment: Yes.  LESS is generating the main.css in the directory target/web/public/main/stylesheets.  However the main.css that gets packaged (via activator "start") into the deployment jar in public/stylesheets has size zero.  Activator "run" delivers a zero size main.css to the browser but I don't know where it comes from on the filesystem.